# WordPress WooCommerce can't checkout after I use php function to hide shipping options

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce

My website is using WooCommerce (Version 6.0.1) without shipping extensions as all physical products will be picked up locally or shipped within only one region, but now I want to add an e-ticket product, no shipping required, using this [event ticket plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/event-tickets-manager-for-woocommerce/) (Version 1.1.1; Pro Version Version 1.0.7).

I created a product category named Events for the tickets and hid all shipping options for this category using this [method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49307885/hide-shipping-methods-based-on-products-categories-in-woocommerce)
I have found here, and although it's working perfectly in hiding the shipping options, when I checkout I can't proceed and instead will get the following message:

> No shipping method has been selected. Please double check your address, or contact us if you need any help

I'm currently setting local pickup as the only shipping option for tickets by using the aforementioned code then setting the shipping id to `display:none` in Additional CSS, but that isn't really what I want, especially since it will also hide the shipping options for physical products.

I have read through lots of posts here but they either only hide some of the shipping options or they just suggest the use of extensions. It'd be great if I don't have to buy a WooCommerce extension to manage shipping per product. Is there's anyway to add/eddit another function in functions.php or WooCommerce plugin file to do that? Or some way to use that line of CSS conditionally? As far as I know, CCS doesn't have if statements, and I am not sure how I can do that in php. Any help on **how to disable shipping for a particular product/category** so that no shipping option needs to be be selected or on **how to hide shipping method on Cart and Checkout page for a particular product/category** should be much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: It's unclear how "for a particular product" should work because you may have several different products in the cart!

Comment: Hi thank you for answering. I have created a category for the tickets and am planning to achieve what I want based on product category if possible. For now I am ignoring the situations where different products/categories are added to cart, as the tickets will only be available for a certain period and I don't want to make things too complicated, so I will assume people who want to buy tickets will only add tickets to cart